# How to disable VS Code's "[AI]" suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to disable these "[AI]" suggestions?

[image: screenshot of VS Code with AI suggestions]

I tried to disable all of my extensions but I'm still getting these suggestions. I also tried to reset all of my settings.

```
Visual Studio Code
Version: 1.85.1
Commit: 0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2
Date: 2023-12-13T09:49:37.021Z (1 wk ago)
Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Code/1.85.1 Chrome/114.0.5735.289 Electron/25.9.7 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: uninstall github copilot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour was found by doing an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to be caused by the [`steoates.autoimport`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) extension. You could disable the extension if you don't actually care to be using it.